# upgrading Angular 2.0 to 5.2 gives 115 errors

Tags: angular, .net-core

I'm using .Net Core 2.0 with angular. I have recently updated all my Angular Packages referenced in my package.json file to use version 5.2.3, I also re-installed Node in-case that required an upgrade to.

My package.json file is :

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^5.2.3",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.5.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.19",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/node": "^9.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.1",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

and the kind of errors that I'm getting are:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"J:/MySolution/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util"' has no exported member 'global'.  MySolution (tsconfig project)   J:\MySolution\node_modules\@angular\core\src\core_private_export.d.ts   19  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"J:/MySolution/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util"' has no exported member 'looseIdentical'.  MySolution (tsconfig project)   J:\MySolution\node_modules\@angular\core\src\core_private_export.d.ts   19  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"J:/MySolution/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util"' has no exported member 'stringify'.   MySolution (tsconfig project)   J:\MySolution\node_modules\@angular\core\src\core_private_export.d.ts   19  Active
Error   TS2305  (TS) Module '"J:/MySolution/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/decorators"' has no exported member 'Class'.    MySolution (tsconfig project)   J:\MySolution\node_modules\@angular\core\src\util.d.ts  7   Active
```

All the errors are related to the angular modules as opposed to my code.

my tsconfig.json file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can use this link as guide. Choose 2.0 to 5.0 and it tells you what to do. https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner this wasn't much use to be honest. One of the upgrade issues it says is to change import from HttpModule to HttpClientModule as soon as I did this it red lined and said that it didn't exist. Presumably because it's not compiled correctly due to all my errors

Comment: well do you have the latest angular dependencies?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner According to the list I needed to add Animations, Compiler-cli and Platform-server, but still made no difference

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I added `"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],` to my tsconfig.json file and the errors have now reduced to 5

Comment: I then changed target to `es6` in tsconfig.json and all errors are now cleared.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: This does, but I'm having other issues now at my backend, because I also upgraded from .net core 1.1 to 2.0. Trying to resolve those now.

Comment: you should at least be able to serve your application via `npm start`